# Best way to traverse data and update nodes in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, angularjs, trees

I am using Angular Tree View in my web app. Data coming from the server is build with

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-materialized

getArrayTree() function.

What I need is, syncing the Angular Tree View with the database.

The first way is sending the final json data to server. And with a tree traversal library ( I'm thinking about https://github.com/afiore/arboreal ) , traverse the tree and update the parentId's of the nodes. But I should make n time updates if the node size is n.

Is there a better way to do that?